# What are A,B,C angles in gcodes of 5 axis cnc machines

Tags: robotics, g-code, inverse-kinematics, cnc

I want to know what is the meaning of A, B, C angles in 5 axis g-codes and how to decode them and make transformation matrix of tool tip respect to machine.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "decode them and make transformation matrix of tool tip respect to machine" ? What kind of CNC machine is this? A Robot? A Milling Machine?

Comment: In five axis cnc milling machines, orientation of tooltip is given by A,B,C angles. I want to know what is the meaning of these angles. in which axes are they measured?

Comment: In CNC machining you have your Cartesian coordinates to represent your XYZ with which I am sure you are familiar and is refereed to as 3 axis machining. When you incorporate multiaxis using ABC, that is the ability to index about each axis so A=Indexing about the X axis, B=Indexing about the Y axis and C=Indexing about the Z axis. So the angles you are asking about are referencing positions relative to your tool or construction plane and coordinates.